# Clean install of 12.04.2 on Asus Sabretooth 990Fx UEFI and SSD

Tags: installation

Is there a simple installation procedure listed which covers a clean installation of 12.04.2 from a USB/DVD which doesn't mention having windows installed first. I want to install using GPT on a new SSD and would welcome advice on partitioning, TRIM and anything relevant. I am also unclear about secure boot for a simple installation of ubuntu on a uefi mobo and references to esp.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to intall Ubuntu 12.10 on the same board using a flash drive an live boot installed. i went in to bios, dragged the usb to first boot, rebooted an followed the prompts. worked flawlessly. also have same ubuntu on m5a97 board with Kingston SSD. booted same way an followed the prompts. However i didnt see or remember seeing any options for trim or partition size. I am not dual booting so the partition did not matter to me. My SSD is a 120gb , by the time install was done i still had 110gb free i believe. i have less now after additional software an such.